# How to loop through array of objects in Node/Express and check if a match exists in MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a web app with the MEAN stack and Yelp API that returns an array of objects, where each object is a local business. I work with this data in the front-end, but before I send a response I want to check if a particular object exists in the MongoDB database and I am struggling with how to do that.

Here is an object that is returned from the API:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Arendsnest",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/arendsnest-amsterdam-2?adjust_creative=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q",
        "snippet_text": "The reigning Lord of Amsterdam beer bars. Popular and seats go fast...come early. Ask for the massive all-Dutch beer list and prepare to have your...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/FurcfTuqaYBv_q34bGTK5g/ms.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bar Oldenhof",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/bar-oldenhof-amsterdam?adjust_creative=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q",
        "snippet_text": "So I'm not much of a drinker. My taste is highly selective and I usually prefer not to drink alcohol altogether. But my husband is the opposite so on a...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/1k57z7ziIW8MyAWHlXWGdg/ms.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Beer Temple",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/beer-temple-amsterdam?adjust_creative=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q",
        "snippet_text": "This is a great place to stop in and have some American craft beer. With 30+ taps and a seemingly never ending list of bottle selections, you have many...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/yxUiYre1Y6ULqMhQ30NPOA/ms.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tales & Spirits",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tales-en-spirits-amsterdam?adjust_creative=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q",
        "snippet_text": "This is exactly what every high-end cocktail bar should strive to have and be.\n\nFriendly staff: From the bartenders to the manager to the waitress. Everyone...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/IElXytpbY0bpp7ZdjFdGvA/ms.jpg"
    }
]
```

This exists in the MongoDB database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57da26d8dcba0f51172f47b1"
    },
    "name": "Arendsnest",
    "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/arendsnest-amsterdam-2?adjust_creative=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=ycRBsh7KEkNFq3wJvKoL6Q",
    "snippet_text": "The reigning Lord of Amsterdam beer bars. Popular and seats go fast...come early. Ask for the massive all-Dutch beer list and prepare to have your...",
    "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/FurcfTuqaYBv_q34bGTK5g/ms.jpg"
}
```

How can I write a query in Node to loop through my array using name property and do a check on every object if it exists in the database and return the data?

Comment: You could use for each loop to get all names and push them into array and then use $in operator in the query `db.collection.find('name': {$in: namesArray});`

Comment: that should work! what if I want to search for a match of 2 properties? for example name and url?

Comment: There are other operator like $or or $and. `db.collection.find('$and': [{name:'....'},{url: '....'}]);`I would recommend to check mongodb docs :)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to do this along with $in operator. The above only works with single name and url. Maybe the only way is to run multiple queries.

Answer (score 2):

No need to iterate the array, use the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator with a mapped array that has the fields you want to query.

Take the following example where you want to search for a match of two properties:

```
var yelp = [
    {
        "name": "Arendsnest",
        "url": "url1",
        "snippet_text": "foo",
        "image_url": "bar.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bar Oldenhof",
        "url": "abc",
        "snippet_text": "efg",
        "image_url": "ms.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Beer Temple",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/",
        "snippet_text": "test",
        "image_url": "ms.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tales & Spirits",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/",
        "snippet_text": "This is exactly...",
        "image_url": "ms.jpg"
    }
],
query = yelp.map(function(item){ return { name: item.name, url: item.url }; });

db.collection.find({ "$or": query });
```

This will create an array that you can use as the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** expression in your `find()` method, equivalent to :

```
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        {
            "name": "Arendsnest",
            "url": "url1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bar Oldenhof",
            "url": "abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "Beer Temple",
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tales & Spirits",
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/"
        }
    ]
})
```

---

For querying on single properties, say for instance you want to query on just the name field, better use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in)** operator which is better optimised for such:

```
query = yelp.map(function(item){ return item.name; });
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$in": query } });
```